# Censors can't approve my Tizen app because they can't play HLS inside my app player

Tags: javascript, tizen

So the thing is that I have an app with some channels. When a user click on a channel, he can see some HTTP Live Streaming.
Here, I can run this app on our Samsung TV and it works greak. When I post it to Tizen store where people need to check it, they can't see the video.
I gave them direct links to HLS and they can see it.
What is the problem?

Here is some code how I set up a player:

```
self.setUrlPlayer = function (url, startVideo) {
        plugin.open(url); // 1. Call webapis.avplay.open()
        self.setDisplayVideo(0, 0, 1920, 1080); // 4. Set media size by webapis.avplay.setDisplayRect()
        plugin.currentUrl = url;
        plugin.setListener(listener); // 2. Set listener event by webapis.avplay.setListener()
        plugin.prepare(); // 3. Call webapis.avplay.prepare()
        if (startVideo === false) {
            // do nothing...
        } else {
            self.event(self.TYPE.LOADEDMETADATA, { videoWidth: 1920, videoHeight: 1080 });
            self.play(); // 5. Call webapis.avplay.play()
        }
    };

    self.setUrl = function (url, startVideo) {
        url += '|COMPONENT=HLS';
        // webapis.avplay.setStreamingProperty("ADAPTIVE_INFO", "BITRATES=" + 50000 + '~' + $('#BITRATE_TO').val() + 'STARTBITRATE=' + $('#START_BITRATE').val() + 'SKIPBITRATE=' + $('#SKIP_BITRATE').val());
        try {
            //webapis.avplay.setStreamingProperty("WIDEVINE", drmParam);
            self.setUrlPlayer(url, startVideo);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    // играть
    self.play = function (pos) {
        if (pos) {
            self.jumpTo(pos, true);
        } else {
            paused = false;
            plugin.play();
            self.event(self.TYPE.PLAY);
        }
    };
```

Comment: please add a coment before downvote!

Answer (score 1):

You can try comparing your code with the example in this guide:

[AVPlay Tutorial](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/media-playback/using-avplay)

Samsung Developers > Smart TV > Develop > Guides > Multimedia > Media Playback > Using AVPlay

[Adaptive streaming (DASH/HLS/Smooth Streaming)](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/adaptive-streaming)

Samsung Developers > Smart TV > Develop > Guides > Multimedia > Adaptive Streaming

Comment: Links are broken.